# WPF Datagrid ContextMenu access Item in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

let's asume that I have a ContextMenu like this

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
   ContextMenu Name="cmNewState" >
     <MenuItem Header="Test" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" />
     <CheckBox Content="CallerId" IsChecked="True" Unchecked="CheckBoxNewState_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBoxNewState_Checked" />
     <CheckBox Content="CallerIdName" IsChecked="True" Unchecked="CheckBoxNewState_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBoxNewState_Checked"/>
```

How can I access in Code behind the single Items in the ContextMenu like

cmNewState......... ???

Thanks a Lot for Help

Comment: Does the `DataGrid` is accessible in code behind? if so, you could loop the `ContextMenu.Items` to get the single Items and do your things...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Can you post the reason, might be there are better approaches to achieve that. WPF is not designed to work like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the items in the ContextMenu names as well:

```
<MenuItem Header="Test" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Name="MyNameHere" />
```

Then you can access them in the code-behind with that name: `MyNameHere`

---

The elements of the ContextMenu are also reachable by accessing the Items-collection that is contained within the Contextmenu as such: `cmNewState.Items[index]`

Comment: Yes that's right, but if I don't wanne do this in that way! I am searching for a way were I can acces the items by an Index!

Comment: I have tried this (cmNewState.Items[index]), but I am not able to access the properties of the single elements like "IsChecked...."

Comment: I got it :

I can Access it by this liitle peace of Code

with((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)(cmNewState.Items[j])).IsChecked = false;

Comment: Be careful with that code, if you cast an item that is not castable to a checkbox, you will get an exception. It is, however, the only way I know of to access the type-specific properties of the items.

I would wrap a try-catch around it just in case (InvalidCastException)... depending on the situation.